# How to pass date in Angularjs datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have a form and I am trying to pass a date using the http post and Angularjs datepicker directive. I am using the bootstrap UI. When I pass the date in console.log  I am just seeing "" for date. If you see anything I am doing wrong or can provide any assistance please let me know. I've tried using the parent.dt as well but no luck. Thanks in advance.

App.js

```
var postData={
            firstName:$scope.newUser.name,
            email:$scope.newUser.email,
            date: $scope.parent.dt,
            termsPhone: $scope.newUser.termsPhone,
            termsEmail: $scope.newUser.termsEmail,           
            telephone: $scope.newUser.phoneNumber
    };
    //postData=JSON.stringify(postData);
    $http({method:'POST',
            url:'sendmail.php',
            data:postData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}})

        .success(function (data,status,headers,config) {

            console.log('Success: ' + data); 
            $scope.realDate = data;
            $scope.modalOpen = true;
            $scope.confirmation = true;
            $log.info($scope.newUser.dt);
            $log.info(postData);
        })
        .error(function (data, status,headers,config) {
            console.log('error' + status + data);
        });
```

Datepicker directive

```
<p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="" ng-model="$parent.dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" date-type="string" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
```

Comment: <mydatepicker  ng-model="$parent.dt" date-options="dateOptions" opened="opened"/>        
    
  <button type="submit" ng-click="formPost();open()" ng-disabled='form.$invalid' class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

Here is the snippet of the html. The other html code is basically a template. This is of course wrapped around a form. And yes, I copied as much as possible from the documentation.

Comment: Is the DatePicker inside an element with a ng-controller attribute? Does that controller have the functions specified in the example JavaScript code?

Comment: Yes, this is inside a controller attribute called 'contact controller'. And the js code above in 'app.js' is the controller 'contact controller'.

Comment: Does setting `ng-model="dt"` and then using `date: $scope.dt,` on the controller work?

Comment: no. Tried this to no avail. Thing  is, using the ng-model all of the other form fields work fine. Just this one.

Comment: What format is your date in? Is it a `Date` object? What is in `$parent.dt`? — if it's in an unexpected format, it won't populate the input field initially.

Comment: Here is what I have which I copied...

$scope.formData      = {};
    $scope.formData.date = "";
    $scope.opened        = false;
  
    //Datepicker
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': "'yy'",
        'show-weeks' : false
    };

would this need to change?